# How to setup ssh for vagrant box creation?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, debian-buster

I try to create a vagrant box of my own and I followed the [instructions](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base) provided by HashiCorp.

After creating the machine, I packaged my box and created a new vagrant test environment (with `box add` and `init`). Everything as suggested in the article above. I always end up with errors on `vagrant up`:

```sh
 default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

The box itself boots and I can also ssh into it, only vagrant seems not to be capable. I already tried ssh suggestions as described in this [blog](https://blog.engineyard.com/building-a-vagrant-box). I replaced the public key, with the official one described in the vagrant instructions and hosted on this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/tree/main/keys).

When I ssh from host into the guest machine (fired up by vagrant) and query ssh service status it says:

```sh
Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 53446 [preauth]
```

Just in case it matters, my guest/box machine is Debian buster, virtualbox is my provider and I am creating everyhting based on vagrant 2.2.17 and virtualbox 6.1.22 (r144080).

What did I miss? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tests, I finally recognized my mistake. HashiCorps says:

> To configure SSH access with the insecure keypair, place the public key into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file for the "vagrant" user. Note that OpenSSH is very picky about file permissions. Therefore, make sure that ~/.ssh has 0700 permissions and the authorized keys file has 0600 permissions.

Unfortunately, I did just flipped permissions ending up that vagrant had r+w+x on the keyfile and only r+w on the folder. As it is said, OpenSSH is very picky... Finally I recognized my mistake and now everything works as expected. It would have been a lot easier with a more detailed error message.